# The execution is not at AddressOfEntryPoint after patching .text section bytes

Tags: ollydbg, pe, shellcode

I have a shellcode and want to inject my shellcode into a PE file (a simple compiled c program that prints Hello World on the screen) . My shellcode size is 0x2a1 and the .text section of my PE file has enough space to hold it . So i opened my PE file in PE-Bear and find the .text section RawOffset in file :

[image: RawOffset of .text section]

then i patch .text section bytes using HxD . I set AddressOfEntryPoint in OptionalHeader to start of .text section where my shellcode is : 
[image: AddressOfEntryPoint in PE-Bear]

So now execution must be started from my shellcode bytes . but i ran PE file and got error :
[image: ERROR] 
I opened PE file using OllyDbg and execution wasn't at position that i expected :
[image: OllyDbg]

AddressOfEntryPoint was 1000 . it's RVA so the execution must be started at 0x00401000 since the ImageBase is 0x00401000 (PE file is not dynamic base) but it isn't that and we got Access Violation .

i use Windows XP . what is going on ? why does this happen ?

Comment: It looks like this binary has a TLS callback(s) registered, that are executed before `main`.

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik Thanks ! there were some TLS Callbacks and i solved my problem by setting the TLS field in DataDirectory field of OptionalHeader to zero :)